# Undo git reset --hard

Tags: git, github, git-reset

I intended to git reset --hard to the last commit I made but I accidentally went back to the commit before that. Is there anyway to undo this.

This was the sequence of events:
1. I pulled from a common repo and made some changes and committed them (SHA1). I made more changes and committed them too(SHA2). Then I made some more changes but never committed them I just wanted to go back to SHA2. Instead I reset to SHA1. Now, all my changes are lost. Can I undo the last reset and get to SHA2?

What I mean is when I did a git log:

```
"SHA2" - HEAD
 Jun 26
 some comment -1

 "SHA1" - Origin
  Jun 25
  some comment -2
```

I reset to SHA1 instead of to SHA2. Can I undo my reset --hard

Comment: If you still have the value of “SHA2” somewhere, you can also just reset there directly: `git reset --hard SHA2`.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I still don't see any of my earlier changes. They seem to have been lost.

Comment: Which earlier changes are you referring to? The uncommitted ones you did after SHA2? Uncommitted changes are thrown away when doing `git reset --hard` and unless you at least added them to the index, there’s no way to get them back.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). It keeps track of many of your local changes, and can be used to recover lost commits (assuming clean-up hasn't occured)